# Cloudify restart livecycle event

Tags: recipe, cloudify

I'm writing a cloudify recipe  and I am trying to manage the HA. In the cloudify doc, i saw the following concerning the "stopDetection" probe:

> It is important to note that Cloudify will invoke the **restart** event if
>   you implemented one and the **start** event will only serve as a fallback.

Does it means that cloudify has a "restart" lifecycle event (such as start, stop)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "stopDetection" life cycle event handler notifies Cloudify that the process is dead and then as a result, Cloudify invokes the "start" life cycle event handler.  - This means that the process is restarted and **NOT** the VM.

Cloudify 2.7* doesn't have a VM "restart" event handler.

If you need to restart a vm via Cloudify, you can use the Cloudify [maintenance mode](http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/developing/maintenance_mode.html).

HTH,

Tamir.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. Let's focus on this part of the quote:
<...**Cloudify will invoke the restart event if you implemented one**...>
This seems to say that I can implement an event to be called when Cloudify will try to restart processes due to a failover. I understand that it is not the VM which is restarted, but some processes.
My goal is to provide my own script to be run when a failover occur, instead of letting the start script to be run again (as a fallback as said in the doc)

Comment: We will fix the documentation ASAP.
It should be something like : 
"Cloudify will invoke the postStop event if you implemented one..."

Comment: Ok. But I it seems quite weird to call the "postStop" as the event for processes restarting :) Is it possible for you to provide a "restart" event lifecycle? It would be great!
Thanks.

Comment: postStop is not restart. I was just referring to your question.
This life cycle event handler is invoked after the service is stopped.

Cloudify 2.7* doesn't have a VM "restart" event handler.

If you need to restart a vm via Cloudify, you can use the Cloudify maintenance mode.